# What does "closule" means?

Tags: word-meaning

I stumbled onto this word in commentaries in some of Onegin and Nabokov's works. I can't find any definition of it in any dictionary.

> This "sustained" comparison between music and champagne, with its disparaging **closule**, 
>   does not really differ much from the "suspended" one between cham- pagne and  "this and that,"

-- Onegin

> And finally, the lovely **closule**:
>
> Had it lived long it would have been
>   Lilies without, roses within
>
> contains in our lady's French not only a solecism but also that kind of illegal run-on which a translator is guilty of, when passing a stop sign:
>
> *Il aurait été, s'il eut longtemps*
>   *Vécu, lys dehors, roses dedans.*
>
> -- Nabokov's Pale Fire.

Sources :

http://www.24grammata.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Nabokov-Pale-Fire-24grammata.com_.pdf Page 143

https://books.google.ru/books?id=l00OTAOKbesC&pg=RA1-PA298&lpg=RA1-PA298&dq=This+%22sustained%22+comparison+between+music+and+champagne,+with+its+disparaging+closule&source=bl&ots=BB2BwcTh95&sig=mk8k3yRjGmovO0w-GBh8DTsuft0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_p5iy543UAhVGEiwKHZAYBj4Q6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=closule&f=false

Page 298

Comment: Please give us the source. I've never met such a word and maybe it is a misprint?

Comment: http://www.24grammata.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Nabokov-Pale-Fire-24grammata.com_.pdf Page 143

https://books.google.ru/books?id=l00OTAOKbesC&pg=RA1-PA298&lpg=RA1-PA298&dq=This+%22sustained%22+comparison+between+music+and+champagne,+with+its+disparaging+closule&source=bl&ots=BB2BwcTh95&sig=mk8k3yRjGmovO0w-GBh8DTsuft0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_p5iy543UAhVGEiwKHZAYBj4Q6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=closule&f=false

Page 298

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The French term is clausule:

Definition taken from the CNTRL (French academy dictionaries online)

A.− MÉTR. Disposition des mots à la fin d'un membre de phrase ou d'une phrase, destinée à créer un certain rythme quantitatif, tonique ou accentuel.

The arrangement of words at the end of a phrase in a sentence or a sentence that is meant to create a certain quantitative, tonic [stress] or accented rhythm.[enter link description here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/clausule)

Nabokov was not really a French speaker and his proofreaders may not have caught this mis-take. He is such a great writer and such a BS artist, as well. That's why he is an interesting writer. Very funny.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, it's a Latin word "[**clausula**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clausula)", look here [Wikipedia - Clausula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausula).

I don't know why the spelling is **"closule"**, at first I thought it should be a **"close"**, however, in English it's spelled as **"clause"**.